# Find $f$ such that the divergence of $(f(\underline{a}\cdot \underline{x}))\underline{x}=1$

Tags: calculus, analysis, vector-analysis

Let $\underline{a}\in\mathbb R^n$ be a fixed vector. Find all functions $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R $ such that the divergence of the vector field $(f(\underline{a}\cdot \underline{x}))\underline{x}$, $x \in \mathbb R^n$ is everywhere equal to $1$.

> Attempt:
>
> I've begun by trying to work out what the vector field I've been given 'is'. So I wrote $$G=(f(\underline{a}\cdot \underline{x}))\underline{x}=(f(\underline{a}\cdot \underline{x}))(x_1,...,x_n)=(x_1f(\underline{a}\cdot\underline{x}),...,x_nf(\underline{a}\cdot\underline{x}))=(\alpha x_1,...,\alpha x_n)$$
>
> and I know that given a vector field $\underline{v}(\underline{x})=(v_1(x_1,...,x_n),...,v_n(x_1,...,x_n))$ the divergence is $$\frac{\partial v_1}{\partial x_1}+...+\frac{\partial v_n}{\partial x_n}$$
>
> The problem I have is that my vector field isn't of the correct form to work out the divergence so I guess this means I've done something wrong? Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong. You must work a little bit more. In this case
$$
v_i(x)=f(a\cdot x)\,x_i=f(a_1\,x_1+\dots+a_n\,x_n)\,x_i.
$$
Now you have to calculate $\partial v_i/\partial x_i$, sum from $i=1$ to $i=n$ and equal the result to $1$.

Comment: So I worked out that the divergence is $nf(\underline{a}\cdot \underline {x})+(\underline{a}\cdot \underline {x})f'(\underline{a}\cdot \underline {x})$. When I set this equal to 1 how do I find $f$?

Comment: Let $a\cdot x=t$. You get a differential equation $t\,f'+n\,f=1$. Multiply by $t^{n-1}$ and rewrite it as $(t^n\,f)'=t^{n-1}$. Integrate to get $f(t)=C/t^n+1/n$.